# MySQL Local Variable returning incorrect results (attempting running balance)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, journal_entries, which stores a trans_id (primary, unique), date, and notes, and then I have a creditdebit table, which stores the trans_id, the credit amount, the debit amount and the account number (that table also has an index named crdeitdebitID, but that is not used in this transaction)

My intent is to produce a running balance, and it works when the results are in their natural order. When I try to reorder by date, I have an issue.

Here is a working query:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT journal_entries.trans_id,
journal_entries.date,
creditdebit.credit, 
creditdebit.debit, 
creditdebit.account_number, 
(creditdebit.debit - creditdebit.credit) AS trans_amount, 
(@runtot := @runtot + ( creditdebit.debit - creditdebit.credit ))
AS balance 
FROM 
journal_entries, 
creditdebit
WHERE 
journal_entries.trans_id = creditdebit.trans_id 
AND 
creditdebit.account_number = '-130'
AND journal_entries.date <= '2011-11-29'
```

Returns:

```
trans_id    date    credit  debit   account_number  trans_amount    balance
1000003     2011-11-10  0.00    10000.00    -130    10000.00    10000.00
1000004     2011-10-25  0.00    2496.00     -130    2496.00     12496.00
```

But when I add

```
ORDER BY journal_entries.date ASC
```

to the end of the query and rerun it in an attempt to get them in the correct date order, I get:

```
trans_id    date    credit  debit   account_number  trans_amount    balance
1000004     2011-10-25  0.00    2496.00     -130    2496.00     12496.00
1000003     2011-11-10  0.00    10000.00    -130    10000.00    10000.00
```

As you can see, the balance, which should be 2496.00 in the first record, is 12496.00.

I am banging my head against the wall.  I have tried creating a VIEW table without the trans_id or creditdebitid, and attempted a balance from those records, thinking the indexes where causing an out of order issue with the local variable, but I got the same results.  I tried JOIN-ing the tables in different fashions, to no avail.  I really do not want to have to store a running balance if I don't have to.  The query above was the original query, and since the more exotic variants produced the same result, I figured I would post the original.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

And FYI, I have been starring at this same problem for 6 hours after 8 hours of good coding, so if its a simple answer, my apologies ;)

Thanks

Edit:

Here are the table layouts:

```
CREATE TABLE `journal_entries` (
`trans_id` int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date` date NOT NULL,
`notes` text NOT NULL,
`input_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
`trans_owner_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
`trans_owner` int(11) NOT NULL,
`reference_number` int(16) NOT NULL,
`payable` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` int(56) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`trans_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

&

```
CREATE TABLE `creditdebit` (
`creditdebitID` int(56) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`trans_id` int(16) NOT NULL,
`account_number` int(16) NOT NULL,
`credit` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
`debit` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`creditdebitID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and an EXPLAIN on an empty query:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  journal_entries     ALL     PRIMARY     NULL    NULL    NULL    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  creditdebit     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   Using where; Using join buffer
```

Here is some data for journal_entries:

```
INSERT INTO `journal_entries` (`trans_id`, `date`, `notes`, `input_by`, `trans_owner_type`, `trans_owner`, `reference_number`, `payable`, `timestamp`) VALUES
(1000000, '2011-10-05', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1323129695),
(1000001, '2011-02-25', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1323129695),
(1000002, '2011-08-21', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1323129695),
(1000003, '2011-09-05', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1323129695),
(1000004, '2011-02-18', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1323129695);
```

Here is some data for creditdebit:

```
INSERT INTO `creditdebit` (`creditdebitID`, `trans_id`, `account_number`, `credit`, `debit`) VALUES
(1, 1000000, -130, '0.00', '19191.00'),
(2, 1000000, -30, '19191.00', '0.00'),
(3, 1000001, -130, '0.00', '19773.00'),
(4, 1000001, -30, '19773.00', '0.00'),
(5, 1000002, -130, '0.00', '5472.00'),
(6, 1000002, -30, '5472.00', '0.00'),
(7, 1000003, -130, '0.00', '491.00'),
(8, 1000003, -30, '491.00', '0.00'),
(9, 1000004, -130, '0.00', '16543.00'),
(10, 1000004, -30, '16543.00', '0.00');
```

And here is my PHP temporary workaround:

Get the results, but I dropped the running balance attempt in MySQL and then

```
foreach($journal_entries as &$journal_entry) 
$journal_entry['balance'] = $running_bal += $journal_entry['trans_amount'];
```

Since the records are already sorted by date by the time they get to PHP, the values come out correctly.  Problem is that when you start talking about half a million journal entries and need a starting balance, this will be slow.

Comment: Is it just me or isnt the return values that you have written above exactly the same but the order is different? The balance is 12496 on both?

Comment: You are correct - but the balance on the second set of results should be 2496.00, then 12496.00.  It appears that they are being calculated out of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Maybe the problem was connected with setting the variable's value.
As a workaround - try to set the variable inside the query, e.g. -

```
SELECT journal_entries.trans_id,
journal_entries.date,
creditdebit.credit, 
creditdebit.debit, 
creditdebit.account_number, 
(creditdebit.debit - creditdebit.credit) AS trans_amount, 
(@runtot := @runtot + ( creditdebit.debit - creditdebit.credit ))
AS balance 
FROM 
journal_entries, 
creditdebit,
(SELECT @runtot:=0) t
WHERE 
journal_entries.trans_id = creditdebit.trans_id 
AND 
creditdebit.account_number = '-130'
AND journal_entries.date <= '2011-11-29'
```

---

**Answer #2:**

That is a MySQL behavior with user variables when ORDER BY clause is added. From the documentation - You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed.

[User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html)

As a workaround of this problem - you can use a subquery:

```
SET @runtot:=0;

SELECT t.*, @runtot := @runtot + t.trans_amount AS balance  FROM (

  SELECT
    je.trans_id,
    je.date,
    c.credit, 
    c.debit, 
    c.account_number, 
    c.debit - c.credit AS trans_amount
  FROM 
    journal_entries je, 
    creditdebit c
  WHERE 
    je.trans_id = c.trans_id
    AND c.account_number = '-130'
    AND je.date <= '2011-11-29'
  ORDER BY
    je.date ASC
  ) t;
```

Comment: I ran your query, with addition of "ORDER BY journal_entries.date ASC", and I got the same result of incorrect running balance.  What I have figured out is that if I reorder the index "trans_id" according to the date (older date, lower trans_id), I get the correct result - essentially the running total is being computed on the records according to the index "trans_id" before the sort by date.

Thanks for your response. The only solutions I am seeing now are either much more exotic, or storing the balance.

Comment: Can you provide tables definitions (SHOW CREATE TABLE) and some data to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: I went ahead an expanded the question to answer your questions (new to stackoverflow, comment don't take well to code :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just posted some data, I went ahead and generated a few extra records to better show the issue.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you - I tested and it works.  I appreciate you taking the time to help me!